Implement a custom test report for Junit5 with gradle grouping the tests by Tag/Tags annotation
I have a java springboot application, what I'm trying to achieve is generating a unit test report that would be later integrated with jenkins to be displayed as a chart or a dashboard.
For now, I tried the default gradle ones, some custom third party libraries, what I achieved so far is generating a report and the tests are grouped by their result (passed, skipped or failed). However, I'm trying to make them be grouped by the Tag annotation, which is the thing I'm struggling with after several attempts.
This is achievable easily with TestNG using groups parameter in the Test annotation.
I believe this would be tackled manually but I couldn't figure it out.
Any ideas how can I reach a solution?
